# How do I use Expo background task while app is terminated?

Tags: react-native, expo, background-fetch, react-native-background-fetch

How can I use background-fetch in Expo for sending phone location to server for every minute. I want task to perform when app is not running in background for both iOS and Android. Is this possible with normal Expo or do I have to eject, what path should I follow? Or at least how can I keep app open in status bar constantly like sports apps with small area or Spotify's music player part?